# mysql select query where date = ... not returning data

Tags: mysql

I've view ReportView

[image]

I want to fetch the result having date 10-Feb-2020

I tried

```
    select * from ReportView where date = "10/02/2020";
    select * from ReportView where date = date_format("10/02/2020","%d/%m/%Y");
    select * from ReportView where date = str_to_date("10/02/2020","%d/%m/%Y");
    select * from ReportView where date_format(date,"%d/%m/%Y") = date_format("10/02/2020","%d/%m/%Y");
    select * from ReportView where str_to_date(date,"%d/%m/%Y") = str_to_date("10/02/2020","%d/%m/%Y");
    select * from ReportView where date = CAST("2020-10-02" AS DATE);
    select * from ReportView where CAST(date AS DATE) = CAST("2020-10-02" AS DATE);
```

Output is empty :

[image]

What actually is happening?

Comment: What column type is `date` in that `ReportView` view?

Comment: What if you try `select * from ReportView where date = '10-02-2020'` ?

Comment: Are you sure that data there is Feb 10th and not Oct 2nd?

Comment: @TheImpaler '10-2-2020' worked. How can I do it with '10/2/2020'? Date format from datepicker is d/m/Y

Comment: What if you use `\`date\`` instead of `date`?

Comment: @dan1st `date` is not working

Comment: it is never a good idea the use SQL keywords as field names.

Comment: @BerndBuffen I agree but escaping might help. This is my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `str_to_date()` to parse the incoming dates, then `date_format()` to format them in the way you have it in the table column.

```
select * from ReportView where date = date_format(str_to_date('10/02/2020',"%d/%m/%Y"), '%d-%m-%Y');
```