# HQL query to select data between two dates not returning any record

Tags: java, hibernate, date, hql, javafx-datepicker

**ReportView**

[image]

I'm getting values of Dates from JavaFX DatePicker objects tDateFrom, tDateTo.

I've tried,

(1)

```
List list = session.createQuery("from ReportView where date between :stDate and :edDate")
                    .setTimestamp("stDate", Date.from(Instant.from(tDateFrom.getValue().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()))))
                    .setTimestamp("edDate", Date.from(Instant.from(tDateTo.getValue().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()))))
                    .list();
```

(2)

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date frmDate = format.parse(tDateFrom.getValue().toString());
Date enDate = format.parse(tDateTo.getValue().toString()); 

list = session.createQuery("from ReportView where date between :stDate and :edDate")
               .setTimestamp("stDate", frmDate)
               .setTimestamp("edDate", enDate)
               .list();
```

Both methods are not returning any row.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2020-02-03"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
```

I've tried to fire query as mentioned in answer of this question : [mysql select query where date = ... not returning data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158392/mysql-select-query-where-date-not-returning-data?noredirect=1#comment106402639_60158392)

But this query works in mySQL, not in HQL. How to use between clause for dates in HQL?

Comment: What is the datatype of `date` in SQL? And which type i `ReportView` in Java? And which Hibernate version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for response!
1) Datatype of date ReportView : java.util.date
2) Datatype of date in SQL : datetime
3) Hibernate Version : 4.3x

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for response! 1) Datatype of date ReportView : java.util.date 2) Datatype of date in SQL : datetime 3) Hibernate Version : 4.3x