# Hibernate Query fetching result between 2 dates

Tags: hibernate, hql

Show me any working example of HQL query fetching data between two dates.

I've already asked this question with description on the following link, but still it's not answered.
[HQL query to select data between two dates not returning any record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182463/hql-query-to-select-data-between-two-dates-not-returning-any-record?noredirect=1#comment106472287_60182463)

Even I tried the solutions on [HQL to query records between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265134/hql-to-query-records-between-two-dates) but not working...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HQL to query records between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265134/hql-to-query-records-between-two-dates)

Comment: I've already tried that approach, and I've linked it with question. Not working.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what exactly have you tried and how it "didn't work" (sample data, expected and actual result)?

Comment: Whatever I've tried, I've already mentioned here : HQL query to select data between two dates not returning any record